# Simple Java Byte Input Stream

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I am currently writing a paper comparing speeds of I/O and NIO.
For that, I need a simple InputStream, that can read 1 Byte at a time. FileInputStream works for loading the whole file, which I needed for another part. But I can't figure out a simple way to load one byte after another like I could do with a scanner for ints. Than I would be able to stop reading once I reached the byte I want to read.
The bytes to be read are randomly generated, so it's no characters or anything fancy.

Is this such a stupid usecase (I know it's pretty on the edge), that it doesn't exist?

Greetings

Comment: [`InputStream#read`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) reads `1` byte at a time from an `InputStream`.

Comment: I just realised, why I thought it didn't work, the output in the console is unsigned and RandomAccessFiles was signed, making the results occasionaly different. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: When you want to compare performances, then this might also be good for you to know/read: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/504103)

Comment: '`FileInputStream` works for reading the whole file': yes, or any prefix of it down to one byte. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class MyInputSream extends InputStream {
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 0x100);
    }
}
```